# WebAssembly's IAuthenticationTokenProvider crashes when requesting a token

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to authenticate the user in my WASM Blazor app using google's OIDC.
I have managed to retrieve the token by following this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

I am trying to retrieve the AccessToken to pass it to the SignalR hub using the injected instance of `IAccessTokenProvider` when building an instance of HubConnection:

```cs
public RemoteCombatListener(ITokenCache tokenCache)
{
    _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl("https://localhost:44364/combat", opts => {
            opts.AccessTokenProvider = tokenCache.GetToken;
        })
        .Build();
}
```

Here is the implementation of my TokenCache:

```cs
public class TokenCache : ITokenCache
{
    private readonly IAccessTokenProvider _tokenProvider;
    private readonly NavigationManager _navManager;
    public string CachedToken { get; private set; }

    public TokenCache(IAccessTokenProvider tokenProvider, NavigationManager navManager)
    {
        _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        _navManager = navManager;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetToken()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CachedToken))
        {
            var requestedToken = await _tokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();
            if (requestedToken.TryGetToken(out var accessToken))
            {
                CachedToken = accessToken.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new AccessTokenNotAvailableException(_navManager, requestedToken, Enumerable.Empty<string>());
            }
        }

        return CachedToken;
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing right now is that when calling the `_tokenProvider.RequestAccessToken()` method, I get the following exception:

```
An exception occurred executing JS interop: The JSON value could not be converted to System.DateTimeOffset. Path: $.token.expires | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 80.. See InnerException for more details.
```

I am unable to figure out what is wrong with my setup as debugging stopped working for me randomly and the only option I have is Console.Log debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that default configuration for the Oidc doesn't request access_token, only id_token. Had to add the following:

```cs
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options => {
    // Rest of configs ...
    options.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = "id_token token";
});
```